# calling an async function from. a custom. thread in c#

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I'm working on some old code that runs on custom background thread. this thread uses the thread class and passes it a thread delegate i.e. an action.

```
_thread = new Thread(() => processData());
```

i need to call some newer functions that return task  so do i just do

```
myfunc().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

or is there some other way? because since it is a custom thread, i don't think if it is really doing anything this time. how can i call async await from. the custom thread so that it is utilized properly?

Comment: `myfunc().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is not an asynchronous call

Comment: but then the work. is handed over to other thread. right?

Comment: It captures the current synchronization context and uses it to resume, it doesn't create a new thread. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33829420/4728685)

Comment: so u mean the background thread calling myfunc() is the one that executes myfunc() ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue using your custom `Thread`, then yes, it has to block on asynchronous code. `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is probably your best bet for that.

> or is there some other way?

Yes. If you can replace your custom `Thread` with a thread pool thread, then you can use `Task.Run` instead of `Thread`, and then you can use the more natural `await` instead of `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Most custom threads can be replaced by thread pool threads, but this is not always the case.