# How is a task with await executed with no additional threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

This is a follow up question to this question:

[If async-await doesn't create any additional threads, then how does it make applications responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419572/if-async-await-doesnt-create-any-additional-threads-then-how-does-it-make-appl)

and to this blog post:

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Regarding the accepted answer of the linked question.. He describes steps of what happens when `await` is called.

He writes there on step 3 and 4 that when that happens, the current thread returns to the calling context which makes the message loop available to receiving additional messages which makes the application responsive. And then in step 5 he writes that the task which we called await on is now complete and the rest of the original method continues after receiving a new message to continue the rest of the method.

What I didn't understand there is how exactly that task was executed to begin with if there wasn't a new thread, and the original thread is busy with the calling context?

So I turned to the blog post, which describes how the entire operation is actually done in much lower levels (which honestly I don't really know how they work) and then there is simply a notification that it was done... But I don't understand why suddenly in the case of the task, you can rely on other hardware for your calculations instead of the CPU which somehow makes it possible not to create a new thread.. And what if this task is some complicated calculations, then won't we need the CPU? And then we return to what I was writing that the current thread is already busy with the calling context...

Answer (score 3):

> But I don't understand why suddenly in the case of the task, you can rely on other hardware for your calculations instead of the CPU which somehow makes it possible not to create a new thread.

Because CPU is not only possible source of parallelism in a hardware devices set.

The threads are logically related to CPU, so for any CPU-bound workload we use threads either explicitly by creating them or using higher-level mechanisms like thread pool or `Task.Run` or implicitly - every application starts inside some default thread anyway.

But there is another sort of operations - input/output operations which imply using other than CPU<->RAM hardware devices such as disks, network adapters, keyboard, various peripheral devices, etc. Such devices deal with data which comes in and comes out asynchronously - nobody knows when you next time press a key or new data arrives from a network. To deal with asynchrony, such  hardware devices are able to transmit the data without a CPU involvement (in simple words a device is provided with some addresses in RAM where data resides and then it can do the transmission by itself). It's very simplistic picture of what happens, but that's something you can think most of the asynchronous flows end with. As you can see CPU isn't required there, so no need to create a new thread. As for the inbound data the mechanism is pretty similar with only difference that once data is arrived it's placed into specific RAM area to be available for further consumption. When a device completes data transition (inbound or outbound), it raises specific signal called interruption to notify CPU about operation completion and CPU reacts on the interruption with triggering of specific code execution which typically resides in the hardware device driver - in that way the driver can send the notification to the higher levels. The interruptions may come from devices asynchronously and CPU is obligated to suspend any current execution it's doing at the moment and switch to an interruption handler.  When a device driver is executing the interruption handler it sends the notification about I/O completion to the higher levels of OS stack and finally this notification hits the application which initiated the I/O operation. How it's done is mostly dependent on OS which the application is running on. For Windows there is specific mechanism called [I/O Completion Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) which implies using some thread pool to handle I/O completion notifications. These notifications finally come from CLR to the application and trigger execution of continuations which eventually can run on separate thread which is either thread from I/O thread pool or any other thread, depending on specific [awaiter](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-anything/) implementation.

As for the general idea of the article you're referring, it can be rephrased with: there is no thread behind `async/await` unless you explicitly create it, because the `await/async` is only advanced notifications framework per se, which can be extended to work with any asynchronous mechanism underneath.

Comment: Excellent complementary with https://stackoverflow.com/a/54351439/4990642

Answer (score 2):

> What I didn't understand there is how exactly that task was executed to begin with if there wasn't a new thread, and the original thread is busy with the calling context?

It's important to note that there are [two types of tasks: what I call Delegate Tasks and Promise Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html). Delegate Tasks are the types of tasks used in parallel processing - the original Task Parallel Library style of usage, where the task represents some amount of code to be executed.

Promise Tasks, on the other hand, only provide a notification that something has completed (along with the result/exception of that operation). Promise Tasks do not execute code; they are an object representation of a callback. `async` always uses Promise Tasks.

So, when an `async` method returns a `Task`, that task is a Promise Task. [It doesn't "execute", but it can "complete"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html).

Comment: So what DOES execute the code of the promise tasks?

Comment: @YonatanNir: Promise tasks do not have code; they represent the completion of the `async` method. The code after each `await` in the `async` method - called "continuations" - will [run on a context captured by `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to understand the level at which the compiler goes to to make `async`/`await` code work.

Take this method:

```
public async Task<int> GetValue()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
    return 42;
}
```

When this is compiled you get this:

```
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<GetValue>d__1))]
public Task<int> GetValue()
{
    <GetValue>d__1 stateMachine = default(<GetValue>d__1);
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.Create();
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int> <>t__builder = stateMachine.<>t__builder;
    <>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
[CompilerGenerated]
private struct <GetValue>d__1 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public int <>1__state;

    public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int> <>t__builder;

    private TaskAwaiter <>u__1;

    private void MoveNext()
    {
        int num = <>1__state;
        int result;
        try
        {
            TaskAwaiter awaiter;
            if (num != 0)
            {
                awaiter = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).GetAwaiter();
                if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
                {
                    num = (<>1__state = 0);
                    <>u__1 = awaiter;
                    <>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref this);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                awaiter = <>u__1;
                <>u__1 = default(TaskAwaiter);
                num = (<>1__state = -1);
            }
            awaiter.GetResult();
            result = 42;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            <>1__state = -2;
            <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
            return;
        }
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
        this.MoveNext();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        <>t__builder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in SetStateMachine
        this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }
}
```

It's the `IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()` that allows the allows the calling code to drop out when it hits the `await`. Note the `return;` in the `if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)`.

It's just a state-machine that does all of the magic.

Comment: I think this skips over how `async` / `await` handles true hardware level IO operations, such as file access, that were present in the other (now deleted) answer.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - There's nothing to do with hardware level IO and `async`/`await`. They are two different and unrelated technologies.

Comment: @Enigmativity: while your answer is correct, the concern here is that it possibly doesn't address the OPs question. This is what Bradley talks about. Yes, async/await and IO are unrelated but we seem to believe the OP asks about how async/await is possible without a thread, i.e. what causes the continuation to start  spontaneously, "on it's own". If this is what the OPs concern is then the state machine is not an answer but IRQ could be an example answer for the IO case.

Comment: Exactly!  When a Task that performs disk IO is started, code can continue to run while data is being loaded from the disk.  To an inexperienced user, it looks like the program is doing 2 simultaneous things; multiple threads must be involved!  I've even encountered this reaction from experienced developers when they are first exposed to async / await. The fact that it can all work without spawning an extra thread is very unintuitive, and plays a large role in why some developers end up not understanding async / await, or just plain get it wrong.

Comment: Wiktor and Bradley are right with what they say about my question. I can accept that an awaited task is performed on lower levels, but what happens when I await on a task which does require the CPU to execute its commands?

Comment: @YonatanNir - Unless a new thread is explicitly created a CPU-bound operation will still block the current thread.

Comment: Just for completeness, putting a `Task` on a different thread is done explicitly by using `Task.Run`.