# asyn await vs await task.run

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

What is the difference in using asyn/await vs await task.run()

await task.run example -

```
 public static void Main()
{

   await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return "Good Job";
    });
    method1();
    method2();
}
```

Async await example-

```
 public static async void Launch()
    {

        await GetMessage();
        Method1();
        Method2();
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetMessage()
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
```

Comment: This resource can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739403/await-task-run-vs-await-c-sharp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013523/when-correctly-use-task-run-and-when-just-async-await and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739403/await-task-run-vs-await-c-sharp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004373/understanding-async-await-and-task-run and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606519/async-await-vs-task-run-in-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When correctly use Task.Run and when just async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013523/when-correctly-use-task-run-and-when-just-async-await)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in the context in which the code will be run. `return "Good Job";` will be executed instantly in the separate task (and possibly on the separate thread - this is determined by the default task scheduler, like `ThreadPool`). In the second one, all code in GetMessage before the first await will be executed synchronously, in the same context as the caller. The rest of the code after `await` will be delegated to the separate task.