# Please explain Timer event async/await syntax

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, timer, async-await

I researched the asynch and await syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078668/explain-async-await-again) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177891/can-somebody-please-explain-async-await). It really helps to understand the usage but I found an intriguing syntax example on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) which I just don't understand.

**Question**:
Could someone please explain to me the syntax of this `System.Timers.Timer` event registration with asynch await:
Why can you use the `async` `await` keywords already in the lambda expression?

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.Elapsed += async ( sender, e ) => await HandleTimer();

private Task HandleTimer()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nHandler not implemented..." );        
}
```

**Question 2:**
And what are the two parameters `sender` & `e` good for if they don't appear in the `HandleTimer` method?

Comment: it's just an anonymous method declared using lambda syntax.  It also happens to be asynchronous.  Which part are you confused about?

Comment: I think the lambda syntax got me confused

Comment: could the people please explain the downvotes to avoid it in future?

Comment: People like to jump on the upvote/downvote train pretty quickly.  I'd say in the future though, try to explain what *exactly* you don't understand.  Literally which part of the expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It assigns an async lambda to the `Elapsed` event of `timer`. You can understand the async lambda this way: first, the following is a lambda:

```
(sender, e) => HandleTimer()
```

this lambda calls `HandleTimer` synchronously. Then we add an await to call `HandleTimer` asynchronously:

```
(sender, e) => await HandleTimer()
```

but this won't work because to call something asynchronously you have to be asynchronous yourself, hence the `async` keyword:

```
async (sender, e) => await HandleTimer()
```

Comment: this is a great explanation. Now I get it, and the two parameters `sender` and `e` are the input parameters for the `HandleTimer` method.

Comment: @MongZhu `async (sender, e) => await HandleTimer(sender, e)`

Comment: ok that actually looks comprehensive. That would mean that if the `HandleTimer` would have no parameters then the event can only be fire inside the class am I right?

Answer (score 3):

This is just an asynchronous [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). It's equivalent to:

```
timer.Elapsed = CallHandleTimer;

async void CallHandleTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await HandleTimer();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you've given is an anonymous function written as a lambda expression.

So what's really happening is that for the timer elapsed event you're assigning the EventHandler as `async ( sender, e ) => await HandleTimer();`.

which translates to something like

```
timer.Elapsed += AnonFunc;

async void AnonFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await HandleTImer();
}
```

It seems that it's the lambda that's tripping you up.

Comment: yes I wasn't aware that one could use those keywords already in the lambda line.