# What syntax is this when setting the Elapsed property?

Tags: c#, timer

Can someone explain me what this `System.Timer` does with the `ElapsedEventHandler`? I don't understand this syntax:

```
private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer7 = new System.Timers.Timer();
this._timer7.Elapsed += (ElapsedEventHandler) ((A_1, A_2) =>
      {
        this._logger.LoggingOfError("T7-Timeout");
      });
```

Comment: funny I asked the exact same question 3 years ago..... [here I found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679480/please-explain-timer-event-async-await-syntax). It's about an async handler, but basically I had the same question about the syntax. If it answers your question, I can mark it as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The code of your question is the same as:

```
_timer7.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
{
  _logger.LoggingOfError("T7-Timeout");
};
```

And that is the same as:

```
_timer7.Elapsed += _timer7_Elapsed;

private void _timer7_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  _logger.LoggingOfError("T7-Timeout");
}
```

You can have explanations about anonymous methods here:

[What are anonymous methods in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008097/what-are-anonymous-methods-in-c)

Comment: thanks! This helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

`System.Timers.Elapsed` is type of `ElapsedEventHandler` which defined as below:

```
public delegate void ElapsedEventHandler(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e);
```

the `delegate` registered for `_timer7.Elapsed` is a [Lambda Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#statement-lambdas) (anonymous method).

`A_1` is `sender`, and `A_2` is `e`.

As a result, when `_timer7.Elapsed` will fired, the anonymous method with arguments `A_1` as `sender`, and `A_2` as `e`, will be called.
That will lead the line `this._logger.LoggingOfError("T7-Timeout");` to be execute

Comment: thanks! This helped me a lot